# Error installing package gulp nodejs

Tags: npm, gulp

Getting Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp' while trying to install gulp

`npm install gulp -g`

Tried running with Administrator ( sudo ) but still can't get it to install.

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/giridhar/Work/Node/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: @GridharBandi please add the error you get when you run as the `sudo` user

Comment: Strange after upgrading npm to latest version 2.11.2 I was able to install using sudo . I think I was in 2.4 version before and I believe partially its my mistake.